# Javascript struct init

Tags: javascript, struct

I am using a Javascript library that requires to define this struct:

```
var options = {
   title: 'My title',
   isTop: true
};
```

I want to initialize the title with a variable so I tried this code:

```
var options;
options.title = 'My title'; // <<< or put variable instead
options.isTop  = true;
```

But this time it doesn't work.

How should I write the options struct, so I can initialize it with a variable too?

Comment: You can use variables and expressions with object literals: `options = {title: whatever + you + want() }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the variable directly:

```
var titleVariable = "My Title";
var options = {
    title: titleVariable,
    isTop: true
};

console.log(options.title); // "My Title"
```

In the property initializer (the `name : value` bit), the right-hand side is an expression like any other expression. It can have anything the right-hand side of an assignment can have.

And/or if you want to assign properties after the fact:

```
var titleVariable = "My Title";
var options = {};                 // Create an empty object
options.title = titleVariable;    // Assign properties
options.isTop = true;             // "

console.log(options.title); // "My Title"
```

Or a combination:

```
var titleVariable = "My Title";
var options = {
    title: titleVariable
};
options.isTop = true;

console.log(options.title); // "My Title"
```

---

Side note: That's not a "struct", it's an object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your `options` variable as an object:

```
var options = {};
options.title = 'My title'; // <<< or put variable instead
options.isTop  = true;
```